# Can I use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to practice Linux?

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu

I am a newbie to Linux. May I ask if I can practice Linux in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows? Sorry for asking such a stupid question. But please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Wait what?  I think you might be a little confused.  Linux is an operating system.  So is Ubuntu.  And so is Windows.  Only one of them can be running at the same time on the same hardware (in general - unless you're using a VM, but that's a little more in depth).  Bash is the Unix shell, so you can run Linux commands in it, however it is not available by default on Windows (again, unless you install something special).  If I misunderstood your question, please comment and tell me, though!

Comment: @cullub he's not confused, and it is available on Windows, althought that's somewhat recent (6 months?). Check [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) for example

Comment: @Aaron Oops!  I was reviewing and didn't see the answers here.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 10, there is now a bash shell built in that can be easily set up. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) to do so.

If you are not on windows 10, I would recommend Cygwin [(download)](https://cygwin.com/install.html) as an alternate program to run bash scripts

Comment: I have started it in my pc but I am not sure whether the command and everything in it is same as those in Linux. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to Cygwin or windows bash?

Comment: I refer to windows bash

Comment: In my opinion Cygwin is *not* a good way of learning Linux on Windows.  I say this having once been tasked to write a training course based on the assumption that it could be used.  There are just too many differences and it would lead to mis-understandings.

Comment: How about windows bash?

Comment: @Mary:  if your question was to me, sorry but I have no experience of Windows bash.  If it is running on a Linux filesystem through Ubuntu then it might be OK, but if it is running on native Windows then there would be differences.  An alternative is to use a Linux virtual machine on Windows through something like VirtualBox (free).

Comment: Cygwin is a generic UNIX emulator, to be the best of my knowledge, and does not attempt to emulate Linux in particular.  Even the new Ubuntu on Windows (which *does* emulate Linux in particular) isn't really going to be the same as actually running Linux, quite apart from the limitations in the beta version.

Comment: Thanks all! I would install the VirtualBox instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will manage to get some familiarity with working with a linux console and some of the commands, however there is certain functionality which doesn't quite work.

What I would suggest though is dual booting Linux next to Windows, to immerse yourself properly and get a clear picture of things from the start.

Comment: Is dual booting something like this?

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: Your reference to that article is correct about dual booting - but I'd actually agree with @cdarke on this one, using VirtualBox to run a VM would be simplest and safest.